# Facebook javascript friend list application

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to create a facebook javascript application - that will take an array of facebook id's -- and display them as a list.

1. Johnny Cash
2. Roger Maleon
3. Mealine Pip

[23432432, 1313232, 43534543]

here is the 
latest jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/94/

-- I've started to try and make the application but its coming up with the error
""An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.""

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title of the document</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

    <script>

var facebookArray = [23432432, 1313232, 43534543]


        var app = {
            getFriends : function(){
                FB.api('/me?fields=id,name', function(response) {
                    console.log(response)
                    if(response.data) {
                        $.each(response.data,function(index,friend) {
                            alert(friend.name + ' has id:' + friend.id);
                        });
                    } else {
                        alert("Error!");
                    }
                });
            }
        }


        $(document).ready(function() {
          $.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });
          $.getScript('//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js', function(){
            FB.init({
              appId: '803898723110754',
              version: 'v2.7' // or v2.1, v2.2, v2.3, ...
            });     
            $('#loginbutton,#feedbutton').removeAttr('disabled');
            FB.getLoginStatus();

            app.getFriends();
          });
        });


        //app id
        //803898723110754

        //client token
        //a10b3f9479bac9cce58aeecd8a037a04


    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Isn't the error message clear enough?

Comment: Also you can not get name from people that haven't logged into the app. When they login to the app and grant permission to the app then you can get their name.

Comment: I don't understand the use case. You have a list of Facebook user ids and you try to resolve them to their names. That's okay, but how come the friends into play? For the first case you can work with an app access token on the server side.

Comment: you can get names of pages by id, but not names of users if they did not authorize your app.

Comment: I just tried it, and it worked. You cannot share the app scoped user ids. Go to the Graph API Explorer, select the app you like to use, get the app access token. And write a user id into the inputfield. For example 4 :)

Comment: @LorenzMeyer - no wasn't sure how to fix it